# Are any standard libraries for Bloomier filters running around?

Tags: c++, haskell

Are there any reasonable implementations of [Bloomier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Bloomier_filters) [filters](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ayellet/Ps/nelson.pdf) in Haskell or C++ running around?  Another question revealed [java-bloomier-filter](https://github.com/egrim/java-bloomier-filter).

I could implement one starting from Data.BloomFilter, but figured I should ask first.

Comment: I just want to say that I love the names of data structures and algorithms like this. It wouldn't do to always be 100% serious, after all...

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Boost C++ to see if its implementation is good for you. There are a couple of other libraries out there, a quick google search should give you a good list :).